# Deleting XML entries after certain amount of time

Tags: php, xml

I have done a search but I can't really find anything related to what I am needing. I am not sure if I am searching for it correctly or not. I have an XML file that is created via PHP and populated with data from a form. What I am trying to do is delete certain entries in that XML file after X amount of time. Is there an easy way to do this or can it even be done at all. I was thinking of some php script that was run by a CRON to check the XML file and delete certain entries by the timestamp after X amount of time. Can someone provide some suggestions or get me pointed in the right direction?

-Thanks!

Comment: What you suggested sounds like a good solution to try, use CRON to run a PHP script that deletes old entries. Alternative options could be to use beanstalk, and create delayed jobs for workers to clean up old entries, however that is probably more complicated than is necessary, depending on the context of this problem

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any examples of a PHP script that will do what I need. I am only a Novice when it comes to PHP. If I could find an example or something I could go off of I could figure it out but my search comes up empty.

Comment: So, is this more of a question of how to remove nodes from an XML document using PHP?

Comment: Hmmmm, that gives me an idea and some direction. I have found articles on that. So I could create a php script to remove a node and have it run via cron but how would I set it to look at the time stamp. I wouldn't need it to remove everything just anything older than 12 hours.

Comment: Have tried to provide some information on this in an answer

Answer (score 0):

To remove the old nodes from an XML file in a PHP script, you would need to parse the XML file, using, for example, the `SimpleXML` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) library.

You can then check each of the nodes in question to see whether a timestamp attribute/child value is less than the current time - 12 hours, and if so, remove that node.

This assumes that the nodes have a timestamp attribute or value - you may need to add this in where you create the XML in PHP, for example

```
<anode created="2013/06/04 12:00">
    //
</anode>
```

Lastly, to perform the date comparison, you will want to use an if statement similar to the following;

```
$timestamp = strtotime($domElement->getAttribute('timestamp'));
if ($timestamp < strtotime('now - 12 hour')) {
    // remove node
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do have a timestamp element. This is what I have thrown together. Would this work. Only thing I am uncertain of is the "VAULEYOUCAREABOUT" part. Which should be the part to check the age correct? http://codepad.org/4g7nz1TQ Here is the XML file. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/mesquite.xml

Comment: Edited to include comparison needed to determine if timestamp is older than 12 hours

Comment: Is this correct? http://codepad.org/9tUj2FS5 I have been messing with this for a couple hours but it wont delete anything. It should delete it all since it is less than an hour. Here is the XML http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/mesquite.xml and here is the output when I echo what the php is saving. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/update.php But it is still showing everything. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxmesqLSR.php I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#84257 shows how to remove nodes which you are iterating - you have to append the nodes to an array and delete them *outside* of the loop.